# Android: show spinning wheel while fragments are created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

How can I show a spinning wheel while fragments are created?

To create fragments I use `_FragmentStatePagerAdapter_`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onAttach() method of fragment to show progress. and you can hide on after onActivityCreated() method

Comment: onActivityCreated will be called for each fragment
how can i call it 1 time when all fragments are created?